# Failed to collect preference classes

Tags: android, eclipse, class, preference, collect

I am new to writing Android applications, so new that my knowledge of Eclipse is so basic it hurts.  I want to know why when I start a new Android project (using only default settings) I immediately get an these errors?

```
Error
Fri Apr 12 00:08:30 EDT 2013
Android Framework Parser: failed to collect preference classes

Error
Fri Apr 12 00:08:30 EDT 2013
Problem loading classes

Error
Fri Apr 12 00:08:29 EDT 2013
Problem preloading classes
```

I am using the ADT bundle downloaded from Google's developer site.  The SDK and Eclipse are up to date.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled the ADT bundle twice now with no success.  Just to be safe I install Eclipse by itself adding the ADT plugin for the SDK myself.  Even with all of these attempts when I start a new project without writing anything or creating any new files these errors occur immediately.

I've been ignoring these errors for a while now being that they were not getting in the way of anything that I have been doing.  Though when I tried to make a new preference file last week I ran into a brick wall.  I have been looking up these errors for a week now and I haven't found one response that is dated this year, let alone given me any type of insight.  What I did notice is that this web site came up with every one of my searches, so I decided  to post it here.

If anyone could shed some light on this problem  would be very grateful.

Comment: Help, help.  Please help.